# Troubles importing project into Android Studio from Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've attempted to export a project through Gradle on Eclipse.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

When I import it into Android Studio, I get the errors:

Error:(18, 0) Cause: startup failed:
build file '/Users/clxxxii/Downloads/l'espace de travail/clxxxii - PMv5/build.gradle': 18: unexpected token: espace @ line 18, column 35.
       compile project(':Downloads:l'espace de travail:appcompat_v7')
                                     ^

1 error

If I comment that line of code, (I figured I could use appcompat_v7 the way a project created from AS would but,) it just finds the next "compile project()" and finds a error to throw.

How do properly import the project to not have these errors? Do I not use build.gradle to import the project?

Here's the file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // or jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':android-sdks:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':Downloads:Android Group Chat App using Sockets:android-websockets-master')
    compile project(':Downloads:JakeWharton-ViewPagerIndicator-8cd549f:library')
    compile project(':Downloads:BaseGameUtils')
    compile project(':Downloads:polljoy-android-master:PolljoySDK')
    compile project(':Downloads:l'espace de travail:appcompat_v7')
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

/////////

here's with the changes.. and with the same error..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // or jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')



    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile ':Downloads:Android Group Chat App using Sockets:android-websockets-master'
    compile  ':Downloads:JakeWharton-ViewPagerIndicator-8cd549f:library'
    compile  ':Downloads:BaseGameUtils'
    // compile  ':Downloads:l'espace de travail:appcompat_v7'
    compile project(":Downloads:l'espace de travail:appcompat_v7")


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
':Downloads:l'espace de travail:appcompat_v7'
```

with:

```
":Downloads:l'espace de travail:appcompat_v7"
```

Comment: now it thows this..   Error:(14, 0) Project with path ':android-sdks:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib' could not be found in root project 'clxxxii - PMv5'. I try adding "" but it still doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @user3439254: Replace `compile project(':android-sdks:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')` with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'`.

Comment: compile project(":android-sdks:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib ")  does not work.. but your answer was right, for that particular issues.. but i see there's a line of issues..

Comment: your right again!!! now it's throwing this.. Error:(21, 0) Project with path ':Downloads:Android Group Chat App using Sockets:android-websockets-master ' could not be found in root project 'clxxxii - PMv5'.  i see the two ways you're switching them around.. so let me try them.. thanks again bro... but i can tell i'll have more issues.. your awesome!

Comment: @user3439254: Yeah, you're on your own for that one, as I have no idea how your project is structured and where this is supposed to be coming from.

Comment: the issue came up again after adding the quotations..  i ended up having to using compile ':Downloads:Android Group Chat App using Sockets:android-websockets-master' for the other external libraries but then the "" solution stopped working. check out my question... i rewrote the build.gradle file.. check i out real quick pleas sir..

Comment: @user3439254: I don't know enough about your project to help you with those local dependencies. The first fix was due to your embedded apostrophe in the path. The second fix was pulling in the Play Services SDK via an artifact. Beyond that, there's not a lot that I can do for you. Sorry!

Comment: Error:(27, 0) Project with path ':Downloads:l'espace de travail:appcompat_v7' could not be found in root project 'clxxxii - PMv5'.  may i have help with this. it's no longer recognizing it..